# file field doesn't gets saved with wagtail inline field

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I'm trying to user inline panels but for plain Django model in wagtail like it's described [here](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/pages/panels.html#inline-panels). I got it working with a plain char field.

When I try to use a `models.FileField` I get an error message after the save action. "No file chosen". It seem it doesn't saves the file

Here is the code I used:

```
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.wagtailsnippets.models import register_snippet
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey


class Slide(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField('PDF / Image',null=True, upload_to="slides")
    mymodel = ParentalKey('mymodel.mymodel', related_name='slides',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


@register_snippet
class MyModel(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('number'),
        InlinePanel('slides', label="slides"),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

How to get the files saved? Should it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that will be fixed in the next release of Wagtail (due in a couple of weeks): https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2251

Comment: thanks. I used the github master version from `django-modelcluster` and it worked :-)